# Change UIImageView's color by file name

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am trying to change UIImageView color , the color changing code works fine but my problem is the method should dynamically change image's color by its file name :

Changing frames image :

```
- (IBAction)fr1:(id)sender {

    mainViewCont.frameImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sf1.png"];

}
- (IBAction)fr2:(id)sender {
    mainViewCont.frameImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sf2.png"];

}
```

changing tint color :

```
- (IBAction)frameColor:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {

    NSString *imageName ;

    for( int i = 0; i < 44 ; i++ ) {

        imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sf%d.png",i];


    switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {

        case 0:
            mainViewCont.frameImage.image = [tintImage imageNamed:imageName withColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            break;

        case 1:
               mainViewCont.frameImage.image = [tintImage imageNamed:imageName withColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

now the problem is only image's tint with 44 number(last image) changes !! and when I press frame 24 it does not recognize the frame image is number 24 .

Comment: Do you know what loop is doing here ? `imageName` is being override and at last it will contain `imageName = sf43.png`

Comment: @TheTiger I edited the post and code but nothing changed

Comment: FRom your question problem is not clear, but you can use Tag, didn't understand why you are using loop.

Comment: of course it only changes the last image. In your loop you are overwriting the image property of frameImage (probably a UIImageView) 44 times. That does not make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your loop you are setting the image property of the UIImageView 44 times. Which means you are seeing only the last image. You only need to change the color of the image that is already set as image.

You should add two instance variables to your ViewController. `imageTintColor` and `imageName`.

You have to add a method named `configureView` which loads the image with `imageName` and sets its `tintColor`.

In your IBAction to select the image you save the name of the image in `imageName` and call `configureView`. In you segmentedControl action you save the selected color in `imageTintColor` and call `configureView`.

Basically like this:

```
- (void)configureView {
    UIImage *image = [tintImage imageNamed:self.imageName withColor:self.imageTintColor];
    _frame.image = image;
}

- (IBAction)img1:(id)sender {
    self.imageName = @"sf1.png";
    [self configureView];
}

- (IBAction)img2:(id)sender {
     self.imageName = @"sf2.png";
    [self configureView];
}

- (IBAction)img3:(id)sender {
    self.imageName = @"sf3.png";
    [self configureView];
}

- (IBAction)changeColor:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    NSString *imageName ;
    for( int i = 1; i <= 3 ; i++ ) {

        imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sf%d.png",i];

        switch (sender.selectedSegmentIndex) {
            case 0:
                self.imageTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                break;

            case 1:
                self.imageTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    [self configureView];
}
```